# Is it possible to use specific cores in R?

Tags: r, parallel.foreach

Consider an abstract code

```
Output <- foreach( j = 1:J, .combine = 'rbind' )%dopar%{
[ BLOCK1 ]
[ BLOCK2 ]
[ BLOCK3 ]
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to specify such that [ BLOCK1 ] is executed on Core1, [ BLOCK2 ] on Core2 and [ BLOCK3 ] on Core3 in `dopar`?

Comment: You can set the so-called process-specific *processor affinity*. However, I don't think R supports this natively, and how to do this is platform-dependent. Generally you shouldn't *need* to do this; the OS figures out a suitable allocation by itself, and this rarely needs to be adjusted. Why do you think it's necessary in your case?

Comment: Many thanks. Specifically, I'm using WinBugs(a software for Bayesian estimation). By `R2Winbugs', R calls for WinBugs, which is outside R.  If I use `dopar`, the same WinBugs is  called from different cores. So, I want to execute WinBugs in BLOCK1, 2, and 3, separately.

Comment: Hmm I don't know WinBUGS but I know how processes are launched on Windows, and changing the processor affinity won't affect which application is executed; this is controlled completely differently, namely via IPC, and is fully under the control of R2WinBUGS. That said, WinBUGS seems to be defunct anyway. Maybe OpenBUGS/R2OpenBUGS might work better.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question (commonly known as an "XY problem"). Maybe this is useful to you: https://rdrr.io/github/fisabio/pbugs/man/pbugs.html

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't know pbugs! I want to conduct a Monte Carlo simulation to investigate the performance of Bayesian method implemented by MCMC by generating data many times. Can I use pbugs in such a simulation study? Or does it just parallelize the chains?

Comment: I have never used WinBugs. I'm just pointing out that you want to use WinBugs in parallel and should look for solutions alowing this. Your question is unrelated to your actual issue.

Comment: It seems that pbugs is out of support now...